How to use special quotation marks?
I want to use the following special quotation marks:
ʼ code point: U+02BC
‘ code point: U+2018
’ code point: U+2019
´ code point: U+00B4
` code point: U+0060
“ code point: U+201C
” code point: U+201D
I have looked at some answers but have yet to find a consistent and simple solution for my problem.
I am writing about preprocessing, so I would like to mention these characters in my text. My last resort would be an image.

Welcome to TeX.SX! With LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX you can type them as it in your source code, or use \char"XXXX where XXXX is the hexadecimal code.

@jlab you can also just type them with latex or pdflatex

All are defined for pdflatex except MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE U+02BC which isn't a punctuation character but a phonetic symbol mark.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

ʼ code point: U+02BC
‘ code point: U+2018
’ code point: U+2019
´ code point: U+00B4
` code point: U+0060
“ code point: U+201C
” code point: U+201D

\end{document}

Produces
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ʼ (U+02BC)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

If for some reason you need U+02BC in the input you could map to a normal apostrophe for typesetting so
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02BC}{'}
\begin{document}

ʼ code point: U+02BC
‘ code point: U+2018
’ code point: U+2019
´ code point: U+00B4
` code point: U+0060
“ code point: U+201C
” code point: U+201D

\end{document}

Works without error.
With a Unicode font then all the characters may or may not work, just depending if the font being used has those characters.
The original document with lualatex produces
Missing character: There is no ʼ (U+02BC) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!

again as U+02BC isn't a standard punctuation character. But a more comprehensive font such as Noto Serif has the full set, this runs without error
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}

ʼ code point: U+02BC
‘ code point: U+2018
’ code point: U+2019
´ code point: U+00B4
` code point: U+0060
“ code point: U+201C
” code point: U+201D

\end{document}

If you have a font that misses U+02BC (Georgia here) you can do as done above for pdflatex and substitute a normal apostrophe.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ʼ}{'}

\begin{document}

ʼ code point: U+02BC
‘ code point: U+2018
’ code point: U+2019
´ code point: U+00B4
` code point: U+0060
“ code point: U+201C
” code point: U+201D

\end{document}


I do have problems with U+02BC. I don't have Noto Serif installed, so I looked up some fonts with albatross ʼ. I used some of these to set as the main font, the document compiles, but the character is not displayed. Am I missing something or is the character just defined as an empty sequence in all fonts I have tried?

@mxcx hard to say if you don't say what fonts that is.

do you get missing character messages in the log? If you do, the font does not have the character, if you don't the font claims to have the character but it may be all white @mxcx

So the fonts I tried are: Times New Roman, System Font Semibold, Rockwell, Georgia, Courier, and Open Sans Regular. And I don't get any errors or warnings

@mxcx with Georgia I get Missing character: There is no ʼ (U+02BC) in font name:Georgia:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;! it works i get this  For the others I'll add a new example

@mxcx see update with Georgia
